# Sending a parameter from every view using hidden_form_tag Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics

I've built a backend analytics API that needs to send Google Analytics client_id from a view to the controllers for every page.

The analytics API works fine and so does the Javascript that puts the client ID into a hidden_field_tag, but the value of the hidden_field is not available in params.

`<%= hidden_field_tag 'ga_client_id' , '', :class => 'ga-client-id' %>`

This is on every page and the value is the Google analytics identifier

`pageview('/signup', 'Signup', params[:ga_client_id])`

This is the API call, used in the controllers. It works fine except for the client id

```
<%= render "analytics/get_client" %>
 <div id="bodyWrap">
  <%= yield %>
 </div>
```

This is where the field is in the layout, so on every page. Within the get_client partial.
Can anyone tell me why I can't access the params from the controllers?

This puts the Google Analytics UserID into a hidden_field_tag:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'ga_client_id' , '', :class => 'ga-client-id' %>
 <script>
   ga(function(tracker) {
    var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
     $('.ga-client-id').val(clientId);
   });
 </script>
```

It's in a partial just below the opening body tag, as shown above.

Then in my 'dashboard controller'

```
def set_complete_status
  if current_user.profile.state.signed_up? && current_user.email_verified?
    current_user.profile.state = 'complete' 
    pageview('/complete-fb', 'FB User Complete', params[:ga_client_id])
  end
end
```

Notice it calls the analytics function on the fourth line after the users state has been changed, adding `params[:ga_client_id]` as the analytics user id.

The send pageview function is below. This functions with the default analytics user id but not when `params[:ga_client_id]` is sent to it.

```
  def pageview(page, title, client_id = "555")
   return unless GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_SETTINGS[:tracking_code].present?
   params = {
      v:   GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_SETTINGS[:version],
      tid: GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_SETTINGS[:tracking_code],
      cid: client_id,
      t:   'pageview',
      dp:  page,
      dt:  title 
   }
  send_analytics(params)
  end
```

Essentially I need access to `params[:ga_client_id]` in every controller, which means submitting it on every page of the site. The only place to get the Analytics User id is from the client.

Thanks

Comment: where are you accessing the `params` variabe from?

Comment: From the controller action. Notice `pageview('/signup', 'Signup',`** params[:ga_client_id]**`)`  It is called from a controller action and calls a function in a concern.

Comment: changing pages does not submit a form or a field so this field is not sucked in by params. If it is a fixed variable why not make is a constant in `application.rb` then it will accessible from everywhere without javascript.

Comment: @SinanGuclu please show the code

Comment: @engineersmnky Where would I set the variable?

Comment: @Малъ Скрылевъ  i've updated the question with more code

Comment: @SinanGuclu have you access to `ga_client_id` in any one of controllers?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ no not in any, i'm trying to get access to it. It's in every view in the hidden_form_field, I need an efficient way of making it available to the controllers

Comment: @SinanGuclu of course, you can't access it from a view, just from controller. pass the variable value explicitly to render.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ The thing is, the variable value needs to be set at the clients side unsing javascript in the view. Then each time the view changes, the variable needs to be posted to the controller. Would it be wise to have a `form_tag` posting to a method in the application_controller making the variable accessible to the rest of the controllers?

Comment: to pass a value to a controller from a form, just insert to the form a hidden field tag, containging the required value. if you don't plan to change it. Then you get it in contoller only as a value of `params` variable hash. But to use it in the form you need to pass it explicitly, or declare it as a class variable (I dislike it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution that's specific to Google Analytics.

When making the call to the method in the concern, I send the analytics cookie with it:

`pageview('/signup1', 'Signup step 1', cookies["_ga"])`

Then in the called method, I call another private method to parse the cookie:

`client_id = parse_cookie(cookie)`

The cookie is a set of four strings separated by dots:  `ga.xx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx` and the last two sets of numbers make up the Google Analytics assigned UID. It turns out you can use anything as a UID for Analytics but in order for the front end data to match the backend, the same UID should be used. The method below parses the cookie, returns the UID as a string which is sent in the HTTP request to the Analytics collector url.

```
def parse_cookie(cookie)
  return if cookie.blank?
  uid_array = cookie.split(".").last(2)
  uid = uid_array.first + '.' + uid_array.second
  return uid
end
```